# Out of money option liquidity issue

Tags: options

One buys an OTM monthly call/put option and after a few days the trading volume goes down and the bid ask spread goes up. He sets a sell limit order based on the Black-Scholes equation but the order does not fill due to low volume. Then how can one sell the option with profit? Or this is not a good trading strategy. In other words, how can one make sure that the OTM call/put option would have sufficient liquidity in future in order to trade at a fair price?

Comment: Would a valid recasting of this question be: how to forecast option liquidity?

Comment: This loss of liquidity once the option has only a limited chance to become ITM is a known disadvantage of buying options.If it happens you have to hold it until maturity when it will (most likely) expire worthless. When you buy any option you should always consider this possibility.

Comment: trade only the most liquid names like SPY

Answer (score 1):

There is not too much to this. As stated, I’d say this is a bad strategy.

You can’t sell the option if nobody is willing to buy it. You can of course lower your price but this new price might not attract buyers or make you unprofitable. Every day you hold it, you’ll lose time value and if the option is still OTM at expiry you lose all premium paid.

Comment: The issue is the sudden drop of liquidity for the particular option and how can screen for that before buying a call or put. One can't trade if there is no market.

Comment: I see, the liquidity in this scenario goes from fairly liquid to illiquid.